# How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}x2^{x}$ without using L'Hospital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to evaluate the following limit:
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}x2^{x}=\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}xe^{x\ln{2}}=\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{x\ln{2}e^{x\ln{2}}}{\ln{2}}$$

I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: This is mentioned in the linked question, but for sake of education: Do you agree that $2^x \to \infty$ as $x \to\infty$? Then for $x > 1$ we have $x 2^x > 2^x$, so ...

Comment: Alternatively, we have two functions that get huge as $x$ increases, and are multiplying them together. What could possibly go wrong? To OP, I would say: you are making things much too difficult for yourself by applying the analytic definition of $2^x$. You should just relax and go with your mathematical common sense.